# Rails has to and belongs to many correct rails association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm setting up my rails association for an app and I'm not sure if my associations are correct for my use case. The use case is: A product can be added once by a user. Once created other users can then add the same product to their own "feed" within the app. I want to be able to do `User.products` to list all of a users products. And for products I want to be able to do something like `Product.where(id: 2).users` to list all of the users that have added the product. I'm currently using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association but I think that this is incorrect for what I am trying to achieve?

User model: `has_and_belongs_to_many :products`

Product model: `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

```
 add_index "products_users", ["product_id"], name: "index_products_users_on_product_id"
 add_index "products_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_products_users_on_user_id"
```

Comment: yep you're doing it right except that the index should be for both, not individual `add_index :products_users, [:product_id, :user_id]`

Comment: why do you think it's incorrect? also, are you trying to store information about each association of a User with a Product?

Comment: I've never been very good at associations. Just a gut feeling and I want to get it right. I think so. What I'm trying to achieve is something like Pinterest where a user adds an image, once added it appears in their feed and other users can also add and remove it from their own feeds.

Comment: as jvnill said, what you have here will work. just bear in mind that if you want to store any information about the association, you'll need a has_many: through relationship rather than a habtm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :created_products,  class_name: "Product", foreign_key: :user_id               #-> created product
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products #-> list of products
end

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user                  #-> created the product
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users    #-> list of users
end
```

You'll need to add the [appropriate `foreign_key`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) to your `User` model (`user_id` in the `Product` model for the `belongs_to :user` association) --

[image]

--

If your `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship is working already, the above should be sufficient.

If not, you need to look up [this documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) to see how it works, and then create a join table called `products_users` (which is populated with the appropriate data):

```
$ rails g migration CreateProductsUsers

#db/migrate/create_products_users______.rb
class CreateProductsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :products_users, id: false do |t| 
         t.references :product
         t.references :user
      end
   end
end 

$ rake db:migrate
```

It will allow you to *create* a single product for a user (IE the `Product` object will have a direct association with the user who created it). The `Product` and `User` models will also be joined with the `habtm` relationship.

---

In your controllers, you could use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products #-> url.com/products
scope "profile" do
   resources :products, only: :index #-> url.com/profile/products
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :product, only: :edit

   def index
      @products = current_user.products #-> if you're using Devise
   end

   def edit
     @product = current_user.created_products.find params[:id]
   end

   def new
     @product = current_user.created_products.new
   end

   def create
     @product = current_user.created_products.new product_params
     @product.save
   end

   private

   def product
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "This is not your product" unless current_user.products.exists? params[:id]
   end

   def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and thoughtful answer. I intend for Users to be able to add multiple products from different sources does the `has_one :product ` still apply in this case? Unless I'm misunderstanding a user can only have one product?

Comment: " A product can be added once by a user" I took this to mean that a user can only add one product. If this is not the case, I will have to change my ansewr

Comment: Sorry poor choice of word. I meant a product can only be added once (it has to be unique).

Comment: So the user can add as many products as he wants, but that product has to be unique?

Comment: Legend very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To be able using has_and_belongs_to_many create association, you must create one temperator table container 2 column are product_id, user_id
you can refer

1. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many
2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association